# make summary table for string variable?

Tags: r

I have a data that is looks like the table on the left, andI want to get a table that looks like right. What should I do. I should be very straightforward but I just don't know how to start it.

[image: summa]

Comment: Please post actual data and code, not screenshots.  Use `dput()` or an actual data frame assignment statement in providing data.  The idea is to allow others to easily copy and paste your example code into their coding environment - that's the easiest and fastest way to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `dplyr` approach. And please next time as mentioned in valious comments add a sample of data using `dput()` and do not include images from data in MS Excel as it can be tedious to copy all values from an image. You can use `summarise()` and `paste0()` in order to reach what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
df <- data.frame(ID=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,2),rep(3,4)),
                 Day=c(1,3,3,5,2,4,4,4,4,5),
                 Result=c('a','a','b','c','c','a','','c','d','f'),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Code
df %>% group_by(ID,Day) %>%
  summarise(Result=paste0(Result[Result!=''],collapse = '/'))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID   Day Result
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1     1     1 a     
2     1     3 a/b   
3     1     5 c     
4     2     2 c     
5     2     4 a     
6     3     4 c/d   
7     3     5 f
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely looking for `base::aggregate()`, which is the standard approach for doing a grouped aggregation in R. The aggregator function should find non-empty unique values.

`aggregate(Result ~ ID + Day, df, function(x) unique(x[x != ""]))`

Comment: Code-only answers may solve the OP's problem, but an explanation will help other users understand why.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[Result != '', .(Result = paste(Result, collapse="/")), .(ID, Day)]
#   ID Day Result
#1:  1   1      a
#2:  1   3    a/b
#3:  1   5      c
#4:  2   2      c
#5:  2   4      a
#6:  3   4    c/d
#7:  3   5      f
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), Day = c(1, 
3, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5), Result = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", 
"a", "", "c", "d", "f")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```